# War Card Game Error

Tags: jquery

Here is the site currently, as is. http://itweb.fvtc.edu/200158947/CardGame/index.html

I am making a War Card Game. The players are each dealt 26 cards when the "Deal" button is clicked. Each time the "Play" button is clicked, each player flips a new card. The winner of the "war" gets the point value of both cards.

My "New Player" button works, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong to deal the cards to the players and assign them the point value if won.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var askName;
    var pName;
    var pName2;
     
    var askName = prompt("Please enter your name.","<name goes here>");
    
    if (askName!= null) {
        document.getElementById("pName").innerHTML = askName
        document.getElementById("pName2").innerHTML = askName
    }

    var used_cards = new Array();
    
    function card(name,suit,value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
    } 
    
    var deck = [
        new card('Ace', 'Hearts', 12),
        new card('Two', 'Hearts', 22),
        new card('Three', 'Hearts', 32),
        new card('Four', 'Hearts', 42),
        new card('Five', 'Hearts', 52),
        new card('Six', 'Hearts', 62),
        new card('Seven', 'Hearts', 72),
        new card('Eight', 'Hearts', 82),
        new card('Nine', 'Hearts', 92),
        new card('Ten', 'Hearts', 102),
        new card('Jack', 'Hearts', 112),
        new card('Queen', 'Hearts', 122),
        new card('King', 'Hearts', 132),
        new card('Ace', 'Diamonds', 11),
        new card('Two', 'Diamonds', 21),
        new card('Three', 'Diamonds', 31),
        new card('Four', 'Diamonds', 41),
        new card('Five', 'Diamonds', 51),
        new card('Six', 'Diamonds', 61),
        new card('Seven', 'Diamonds', 71),
        new card('Eight', 'Diamonds', 81),
        new card('Nine', 'Diamonds', 91),
        new card('Ten', 'Diamonds', 101),
        new card('Jack', 'Diamonds', 111),
        new card('Queen', 'Diamonds', 121),
        new card('King', 'Diamonds', 131),
        new card('Ace', 'Clubs', 13),
        new card('Two', 'Clubs', 23),
        new card('Three', 'Clubs', 33),
        new card('Four', 'Clubs', 43),
        new card('Five', 'Clubs', 53),
        new card('Six', 'Clubs', 63),
        new card('Seven', 'Clubs', 73),
        new card('Eight', 'Clubs', 83),
        new card('Nine', 'Clubs', 93),
        new card('Ten', 'Clubs', 103),
        new card('Jack', 'Clubs', 113),
        new card('Queen', 'Clubs', 123),
        new card('King', 'Clubs', 133),
        new card('Ace', 'Spades', 14),
        new card('Two', 'Spades', 24),
        new card('Three', 'Spades', 34),
        new card('Four', 'Spades', 44),
        new card('Five', 'Spades', 54),
        new card('Six', 'Spades', 64),
        new card('Seven', 'Spades', 74),
        new card('Eight', 'Spades', 84),
        new card('Nine', 'Spades', 94),
        new card('Ten', 'Spades', 104),
        new card('Jack', 'Spades', 114),
        new card('Queen', 'Spades', 124),
        new card('King', 'Spades', 134)
    ];
    
    $("#btnDeal").click( function(){
        deal();
        $(this).toggle();
    });
    
    var hand = {
        cards : new Array(),
        current_total : 0,
        
        sumCardTotal: function(){
            this.current_total = 0;
            for(var i=0;i<this.cards.length;i++){
                var c = this.cards[i];
                this.current_total += c.value;
            }
            $("#hdrTotal").html("Total: " + this.current_total );
        }
    };
    
    function getRandom(num){
        var my_num = Math.floor(Math.random()*num);
        return my_num;
    }
    
    function deal(){
        for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
            hit();
        }
    }
    
    function hit(){
        var good_card = false;
        do{
            var index = getRandom(134);
            if( !$.inArray(index, used_cards ) > -1 ){
                good_card = true;
                var c = deck[ index ];
                used_cards[used_cards.length] = index;
                hand.cards[hand.cards.length] = c;    
                
                var $d = $("<div>");
                $d.addClass("current_hand")
                  .appendTo("#my_hand");
                          
                $("#PlayerCards").attr('alt', c.name + ' of ' + c.suit )
                          .attr('title', c.name + ' of ' + c.suit )
                          .attr('src', 'images/cards/' + c.suit + '/' + c.name + '.jpg' )
                          .appendTo($d)
                          .fadeOut('slow')
                          .fadeIn('slow');
            }
        } while(!good_card);
        good_card = false;      
        hand.sumCardTotal();
    }
    
    $("#btnRestart").click( function(){
        $("#result").toggle();
        $(this).toggle();
        $("#my_hand").empty();
        $("#hdrResult").html('');
        $("#imgResult").attr('src','images/check.png');
        
        used_cards.length = 0;
        hand.cards.length = 0;
        hand.current_total = 0;
        
        $("#btnDeal").toggle()
                     .trigger('click');
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: green;
}

#main {
    width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
    color: coral;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
}

#pHand, #cHand {
    width: 299px;
    height: 500px;
    color: coral;
}

#pHand .pName, #cHand h2 {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#pHand {
    float: left;
    background-color: bisque;
    border-right: 2px dashed black;
}

#cHand {
    float: right;
    background-color:  bisque;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    width: 225px;
    height: 555px;
    background-color: green;
}

#right h2, #right p {
    display: inline-block;
    color: coral;
}

#right p {
    font-size: 32px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#right.pName, #cName {
}

#but {
    clear: both;
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color: coral;
}

#PlayerCards {
    padding-left: 50px;
}

#SlickCards {
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Card Game</title> 
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <h1> Card Game </h1>
        <div id="left">
             
        <div id="pHand">
            <h2 id="pName" class="pName" type ="text">Player</h2> 
            <img id="PlayerCards" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8IKJ.png" alt="player" width="200" height="350">
        </div>
        <div id="cHand">
            <h2>Slick</h2>
            <img id="SlickCards" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0d9c.png" alt="slick" width="200" height="350">
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <button id="newplayer" onclick="myFunction()">New Player</button>
            <button id="btndeal" onclick="Function1()">Deal</button>
            <button id="btnplay">Play</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div id='right'>
        <!-- Enter the number of remaining cards in the 'Players' hand 
        in the p tag below--> 
        <p id="cardCount">Card Count: <p id="count"></p></p><br />
        <h2 id="pName2" class="pName">Player</h2>
        <!-- Using jQuery insert the current 'Player' score in the p tag 
             below -->
        <p id="pScore" ></p><br />
        <h2 id="cName">Slick</h2>
        <!-- Using jQuery insert the current 'Slick' score in the p tag 
             below -->
        <p id="cScore"></p>
        <!-- add and style winning message in the 
             following div -->
        <div id="win">  </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        location.reload();
    }

    function Function1() {
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "26";
        document.getElementById("pScore").innerHTML = "0";
        document.getElementById("cScore").innerHTML = "0";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: perhaps you can make your question a little smaller in scope and be more specific about what you are hoping for an answer to?

Comment: I put your code into a `snippet` and it seems to run, where is the problem you are looking to fix exactly?

Comment: Side note but a good way to deal out everything without having to deal with occurrences of cards already in use is to get a random number from 0 to array.length -1, and then remove that card from the array.

Comment: @nurdyguy yes!  the `deck of cards` it is such a commonly used example in documentation, it is like a favorite story line.  My favorite is a randomly built list (deck) in `Redis`, and then popping one off the top as they are dealt.  I like the simple UI that OP has here, but I would abstract the code a bit more personally.  Alas, this is (was) a front-end question though.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I guess I'm just not sure why my card images don't appear when I hit the play button. If anyone has suggestions as to what I could change, I would appreciate it!! @NappingRabbit

Comment: @AllisonGandara The problem is the `btnplay` button doesn't have an onclick handler. So nothing happens when you click it.